# Sort a custom column in Woocommerce Admin Order List

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've added a column to my Admin Order section in Woocommerce that pulls a custom field from a WooCommerce membership and displays that value alongside the order - essentially, if a customer is a subscriber, they have a subscriber number assigned to their account (by me) and I want that subscriber number to show up alongside orders that subscriber places - and ideally would like to sort the order screen by that number. Here's the code I've used to get the subscriber number to show up:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_custom_shop_order_column' );
function add_custom_shop_order_column( $columns ) {
    $order_actions = $columns['order_actions'];
    unset($columns[ 'order_actions' ]);

    // add custom column
    $columns['sub_number'] = __('Sub Number', 'woocommerce');

    // Insert back 'order_actions' column
    $columns['order_actions'] = $order_actions;

    return $columns;
}
// populate custom column
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'woocommerce_show_sub_number_column', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_show_sub_number_column( $column_name, $order_id ) {
    switch ( $column_name ) {
        case 'sub_number':
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            $note = $order->get_user_id();
            $data = get_user_meta($note);
            if ( $data['_wc_memberships_profile_field_requested_number'][0] ) {
                $subNumber = $data['_wc_memberships_profile_field_requested_number'][0];
            }
            if ( !empty($subNumber) ) {
            echo $subNumber;    
            } else {
            echo 'N/A';
            }
            break;
    }
}

// Make custom column sortable
add_filter( "manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns", 'shop_order_column_meta_field_sortable' );
function shop_order_column_meta_field_sortable( $columns )
{
    $meta_key = '_wc_memberships_profile_field_requested_number';
    return wp_parse_args( array('sub_number' => $meta_key), $columns );
}
```

So far, so good. I've tried a number of different things to make this custom column sort in numeric order, but everything I've tried doesn't work. I'm wondering if the problem is because all of the solutions I've seen sort a value on the order, and what I'm trying to sort by is actually a value stored elsewhere - but am at a loss to figure out how to bridge the gap. Would appreciate any tips you all might have!

Example sorting code that's not working:

```
// Make sorting work properly (by numerical values)
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_request_orderby');
function custom_request_orderby($query)
{
    if (!is_admin()) return;
    
    $orderby = $query->get('orderby');
    switch($orderby){
        case 'sub_number':
            $query->set('meta_key', '_wc_memberships_profile_field_requested_number');
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
            break;
        default:break;
```

Comment: You can only sort Order metadata, but not user metadata… So when you add a "sub_number" to a customer, you also need: 1) to add this 'sub_number' to all existing orders for that customer. 2) Also, when an order is placed, you need to check if the"sub_number" exists for the current customer and add it to the order  as custom order metadata. Then you will be able to sort orders from "sub_number" column.